# Drag and drop images from WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In a traditional web browser (Chrome, IE, etc.), I can grab an image and drag it somewhere else, and depending on the application, I can drop the image and something will happen: it will be displayed, opened, saved, etc.

In the application I'm working on, I've added event handlers and code to download and display an image if you drag and drop it onto one of the PictureBoxes on the form. Works great, no problems with that.

For whatever reason, if I load a page in a WebBrowser control, I can't drag images from the page that's loaded. At first I thought maybe I had changed a property of the control that was disabling this functionality, but I created a brand new project with nothing but a WebBrowser on the form and pointed it to a few different pages with images. Even pointing it to a local file with just an img tag in it, I cannot get it to drag images out of the displayed pages. If I select text, I'm able to drag that text out, but no images.

Is there a property I'm missing that I need to set to enable this functionality?

Running in .NET 4 on Win 7 x86 with IE 10 and the registry key to cause the WebBrowser class to use the IE 10 engine. (also tried disabling that and going back to the default IE 7 engine)

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't found an answer to the actual issue, but I found that wrapping my img tag with an anchor with href set to the image path, I can now drag and drop that anchor in the normal way. Drop event handler still manages to get a file path that works, and I have no problem setting the WebBrowser control's AllowNavigation to false. Couple CSS changes and I'm done.